# Lenovo X1 Nano with Ubuntu 20.04.2 didn't activate 4-speaker

Tags: sound, configuration, thinkpad, nano

Everything seems to work fine on the Thinkpad X1 Nano except the sound. Only the bottom-speakers make an accurat sound. But I couldn't hear anything from the upward-speakers. Anybody with the same Problem? Anybody with a solution?

System:
Ubuntu 20.04.2
Kernel 5.8.0-43-generic

It seems to be a HDA Problem, but the backgrounds are very complex...

Have a great Day!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you need to use Pulse Audio to change the **Audio Controller**. Play some audio and switch to "Input".

[image: Change sound]